# Getting KeyError: groups from ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook, arcgis-notebook

I am working on ArcGIS Notebooks

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from IPython.display import display
agol_gis = GIS("https://*********.maps.arcgis.com/home/")
agolSiteAdmin = agol_gis.users.get('siteadmin')
print(agolSiteAdmin.groups)
```

I am getting following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arcgis/gis/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, k)
   5714         try:
-> 5715             return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
   5716         except KeyError:

KeyError: 'groups'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-b0f847f656f3> in <module>
      1 # Print all groups
----> 2 print(agolSiteAdmin.groups)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arcgis/gis/__init__.py in groups(self)
   5883     def groups(self):
   5884         """Gets a list of Group objects the current user belongs to."""
-> 5885         return [Group(self._gis, group['id']) for group in self['groups']]
   5886     #----------------------------------------------------------------------
   5887     def update_license_type(self, user_type):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arcgis/gis/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, k)
   5717             if not self._hydrated and not k.startswith('_'):
   5718                 self._hydrate()
-> 5719             return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
   5720 
   5721     def __str__(self):

KeyError: 'groups'
```

I am using the following version

```
# packages in environment at /opt/conda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ipython                   7.5.0            py36h39e3cac_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0    defaults
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

users.get in the Python API for AGOL requires the actual username in Portal or AGOL of one of you account members. While using "siteadmin" returns a result this is not the actual administrator of your AGOL account unless they have the username of "siteadmin".

Provide a username for an account within your Portal or AGOL organization and provided that they belong to groups in AGOL you will be able to use `print(agolSiteAdmin.groups)` successfully.

Here is the documentation [users.get](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.UserManager.get)